# Laravel - Eloquent subquery select independent from model scenario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use a sub query in laravel's eloquent orm and there are many examples out there but my scenario is somehow different. Laravel's eloquent orm focuses on model (every table has a model) but my subquery is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (Select * FROM Table Where id <> 12) t WHERE phone = '123456' Or email = 'example@example.com'
```

So basically why am i doing this? I want to check/get all the rows where **phone** is 123456 or **email** is example@example.com **EXCEPT** the row where id is **12**. What approach should i use?

Comment: I am in document databases now (using orientdb) that's why i did it this way. if there is a better approach to do this mysql query that can fit into eloquent model. I would appreciate.

Comment: Why not just `select * from table where (phone = '123456' or email = 'example') and id <> 12`?

Comment: @patricus, Thanks mate, This query helped me. If you can write it in the answer with a little bit explanation that why this sub query can't work in eloquent. so that i mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing raw SQL queries, which have relatively little to do with Laravel's Eloquent ORM / Query Builder.

The following statement would be the Eloquent version if you want to select all the rows where phone is 123456 or email is example@example.com EXCEPT the row where id is 12:

```
MyModel::where('phone', '12345')->orWhere('email', 'example@example.com')->whereNotIn( 'id', [12])->get();
```

On a side note, `whereNotIn` accepts an array as parameter, hence you could also write:

`whereNotIn( 'id', [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Thanks for the clean solution